# My code cannot find an array that I have already declared

Tags: java, arrays, object

Here is my code. The problem occurs in the `for` loop when I'm trying to place the object `newCar` into the array of cars. It says that `Car[]` cannot be resolved to a variable, even though I declared it on the fourth line of code.

```
public class Race {
    public double distance;
    public String raceType;
    public Car[] carsEntered = new Car[3];
    final int DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_CARS = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int carCount = 0;
        String winner;

        Car myCar = new Car("Chase", 75);
        Car ProfCar = new Car("Prof. Harms", 85);
        Car JeffCar = new Car("Jeff Gordan", 100);
    }
    public void changeDistace(double newDistance) {
        distance = newDistance;
    }
    public void changeRaceType(String newRaceType) {
        raceType = newRaceType;
    }
    public void addCar(Car newCar) {
        boolean carPlaced = false;
        for (int i=0; i < DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_CARS; i++) {
            if (carPlaced == false) {
                if (Car[i] == null) {
                    Car[i] = newCar;
                    carPlaced = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is not the only .java file in the project. The car object is declared and works fine in my other code, I just need to know why this array that I have declared (`Car[]`) isn't recognized in the `for` loop in `addCar()`.

Comment: Maybe use `carsEntered[i]` instead of `Car[i]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Car[]` is the type of the variable, not the name. The variable is named `carsEntered`.